# Get the User Id of the user whose session ID I have using REST API

Tags: rest-api, soap-api

I have the Session Id(00Di0000000cm9A!ARIAQG4qWqmIxCCrnXRDFR2cPXt6KElMUaMvFTlhLyrr56bYwPyWZYXYjb4XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX) and instance URL(na15) of a salesforce org , 
Now I want to get the User Id of the user whose session ID I have.

I am using the below code to querying that user

```
final PageReference theUrl = new PageReference(SERVER_URL + '/services/data/v22.0/query/');

theUrl.getParameters().put('q','Select a.Phone, a.Name, a.Industry From Account a limit 20');

    request = new HttpRequest();
    request.setEndpoint(theUrl.getUrl());
    request.setMethod('GET');
    request.setHeader('Authorization', 'OAuth ' + SESSION_ID);

    String body = (new Http()).send(request).getBody();

    JSONParser parser = JSON.createParser(body);

    do
    {
        parser.nextToken();
    }
    while(parser.hasCurrentToken() && !'records'.equals(parser.getCurrentName()));

    parser.nextToken();

    acc = (List<Account>) parser.readValueAs(List<Account>.class);
```

Please help

Thanks

Ankit

Comment: You are querying Account in your code not User.

Comment: Right , I can query user as well, but it will give me all the users, not the user whose session I have.
theUrl.getParameters().put('q','Select id from user where IsActive= true');

Answer (score 2):

If you can make calls to the Chatter REST API, you can use the value of the id property returned from this request:

```
GET /services/data/vXX.0/chatter/users/me
```

where XX is 23 or greater.

Documentation: http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/chatterapi/Content/connect_resources_users_UserProfileInformation.htm

Answer (score 1):

A **wrong answer** (see Ankit's fist comment below):

On what the User query should look like, try:

```
'Select Id from User where Id = :UserInfo.getUserId()'
```

which should return the required single row.

Comment: if I put this like

theUrl.getParameters().put('q','Select Id from User where Id = :UserInfo.getUserId()');


It will give error:-


unexpected token: ':' (Bind variables only allowed in Apex code)","errorCode":"MALFORMED_QUERY"}

Comment: My apologies then my answer is wrong. I'll delete it in a few minutes. Good luck.

Comment: That's Fine Keith, 
Can you suggest me an approach or any alternate way to get this done.

Thanks for your help

Comment: I presume you do not have the User.UserName related to the session id; if you did you could query using that as it is unique.

Comment: No , I dont have User.UserName , all I have is Session id and Instance url. I am free to do anythind with it to get this done.

Comment: It would be a hack, but if you inserted an SObject that has an OwnerId field and then queried it back the SObject OwnerId field for most SObjects would be the User Id. But I would hope there is a better way than that.

Comment: If you don't mind using another non-REST API http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13133651/get-userid-from-the-session-id-and-server-url.

Comment: Thanks keith


The link you have provided might not works for me, because it is being written in 3rd party tool like jave or .NET

But I feel your hack of inserting a record and then get the ownerid would do the trick, although it can only be used as a backup plan.




I have figured out an alternate approach by using the RestResource class, where i create a method with @HttpGet annotation and return the userid as body of HttpResponse.

Thanks

Comment: Agree that a custom @RestResource is better. Just brings the pain of having to be included in profiles.

Answer (score 0):

I know you're using the REST API in your sample code, but since the question is tagged soap-api I'll mention there's a SOAP call that's very useful for this, and exposes the equivalent of the apex UserInfo static methods.

[Take a look at the getUserInfo() SOAP method docs.](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api/Content/sforce_api_calls_getuserinfo.htm)