# How to Query for logged in username [Python:SimpleSalesforce]?

Tags: soql, rest-api, query, python, simple-salesforce

Tried to do

`user=sf.query("SELECT Id, Name FROM User WHERE Id = :UserInfo.getUserId()"`

but getting error:

```
content = [{u'errorCode': u'MALFORMED_QUERY', u'message': u'\nSELECT Id, Name from User Where Id = :UserInfo....olumn:37\nBind variables only allowed in Apex code'}] 
      message = u'Malformed request {url}. Response content: {content}' 
      resource_name = 'query' 
      status = 400 
      url = u'https://salesforce.com/services/data/...er+Where+Id+%3D+%3AUserInfo.getUserId%5C%28%5C%29
```

Comment: How did you log in if you do not already know the Username? Your question and your title differ slightly. Ostensibly, you already know `Username`, since you logged in. Filtering on this field should provide what you need.

Comment: It's possible to initiate a session in `simple_salesforce` with an access token passed from an external source, so it's possible the Python script doesn't know its own username. You can get it from the API, though; I'll post a Python example.

Comment: Login is through oauth using a salesforce app to get token @AdrianLarson

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't use Apex binding (`:UserInfo.getUserId()`) in Python.

`simple_salesforce`'s connection object has a method `restful()` that lets you make arbitrary REST API calls. Let's say you're getting your Session ID and Instance URL as environment variables. You might start a session like this:

```
connection = Salesforce(
    instance_url=os.environ['INSTANCE_URL'],
    session_id=os.environ['ACCESS_TOKEN']
)
```

Now, I'll show two routes to the username for the price of one (perhaps there's others, too).

### Identity URL

```
identity_url = connection.restful('')['identity']
```

yields a URL like

```
https://test.salesforce.com/id/00DL0000005XXXXMAA/005L0000004XXXXIAA
```

whose final component is the User Id. You can grab that element and pass it to `simple_salesforce`'s normal retrieve mechanism:

```
my_user = connection.User.get(identity_url[-18:])
```

The resulting dict will contain all the attributes you expect for your User record, including the user name.

### Chatter API

You can also obtain the user name by doing

```
user_name = connection.restful('chatter/users/me')
```

The resulting dict also contains extensive user information, including a key `username`.

See [alouie's answer to this question](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/29497/get-the-user-id-of-the-user-whose-session-id-i-have-using-rest-api). Note that this endpoint does [require Chatter to be turned on](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.chatterapi.meta/chatterapi/connect_resources_users_UserProfileInformation.htm).

Comment: Two for the price of one? how much is the price of one haha. Thank you so much! You're the MVP